# Able Particle Tracker

Tags: tracking, computer-vision

I recently watched a youtube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bZXKv-wsos) of a computer program tracking particles and other objects. 
Since I dont tend to find much about multi object tracking when searching, does any one have any ideas what algorithms could be in use here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps: http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/hess/code/particles/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that he is doing simple normalized cross correlation in a small search area around each particle for every frame. The particles tracked are very easy to identify in this case. I highly doubt they are using a particle filter (the name is misleading, a particle filter doesnt mean its tracking a particle).